# dapper populate DropDownlist

Tags: orm, dapper

I have a simple Poco

```
public virtual short UserID
{
  get;
  set;
}

[Required]
public virtual string UserName
{
  get;
  set;
}
public virtual string Password
{
  get;
  set;
}

public virtual string Email
{
  get;
  set;
}
```

Im currently Using Dapper ORM.

Does anyone have a good example of how I would query using dapper ORM to create a drop-down-list?

The query should return `Key=UserID` and `Value=UserName` in a list so that I can retrieve the keys and populate the DropDownList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a class representing the pair:

```
class SelectItem
{
    public long Key {get;set;}
    public string Value {get;set;}
}

var list = connection.Query<SelectItem>(" select id Key UserName Value from yourtable",null).ToList();
```

you use the aliases to map the table fields to the class properties names. I'm supposing your table field names are `id` and `UserName`, change them according to your case.
You should also pay attention to the property types, you can have a bad cast exception if they don't match.
ALternatively, you can use the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) version:

```
 var list = connection.Query(" select id Key UserName Value from yourtable",null).ToList();
```

you obtain a list of dynamics each with property named Key and UserName.